# How to Read a Text file Using Actionscript 3?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, text-files

I am trying to read a text file in my air project. It is actually the config file used by TinkerProxy. I have the following so far:

```
//Read settings from TinkerProxy Config File
var TextFileLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var ArrayOfLines:Array;
TextFileLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
TextFileLoader.load(new URLRequest("/tinkerproxy-2_0/serproxy.cfg"));
//TextFileLoader.dataFormat    = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    ArrayOfLines = e.target.data.split(/\r/);
    trace(e.target.data);
}

trace(ArrayOfLines[0]);
```

What I'm really trying to do is find the 'net_port1=5331' entry and store '5331' in a variable.

Here is a sample of the text file:

```
# Generated by TinkerProxy Configurator
# 

# Timeout in seconds
# 0 means infinite, no timeout

timeout=0
newlines_to_nils=false

comm_ports=1 

serial_device1=COM1
net_port1=5331
comm_baud1=9600
comm_databits1=8
comm_stopbits1=1
comm_parity1=none
```

The file is autogenerated so I can not edit it (or rather I'd want to read it as it is generated.)

I'm able to see the data via `trace(e.target.data)` but I cannot access the data via `trace(ArrayOfLines[0]);` for instance.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried `ArrayOfLines = e.target.data.split(/\n/);` as well. No joy yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to split on [`\n` (Unix) or `\r\n` (Windows)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), not `\r`.

Usually when loading a text file from the filesystem and breaking into lines, I normalize line endings by doing this:

```
var lines:Array = text.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split("\n");
```

Then you can iterate over the lines and decode each line as desired. The file appears to be akin to [.properties format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties), for which there is no built in parser in AS3 (like XML, JSON, or URLVariables) but it's a pretty simple format. For example, this:

```
var props:Object = {};
for each(var line:String in lines){
    // skip blank lines and comment lines
    if(line == "" || line.charAt(0) == "#")
        continue;
    var arr:Array = line.split("=");
    if(arr.length == 2)
        props[arr[0]] = arr[1];
}

trace(JSON.stringify(props, null, 2))
```

Outputs this:

```
{
  "comm_parity1": "none",
  "comm_ports": "1 ",
  "newlines_to_nils": "false",
  "comm_baud1": "9600",
  "serial_device1": "COM1",
  "comm_databits1": "8",
  "timeout": "0",
  "comm_stopbits1": "1",
  "net_port1": "5331"
}
```

Which allows you to access properties by name:

```
trace(props.net_port1); // "5331"
```

(Note that all values are strings, so for example `newlines_to_nils` is not `false`, it is `"false"`.)

Alternatively, you could search for the key you are looking for and extract just the data you want:

```
var key:String = "net_port1=";
var index:int = text.indexOf(key);
if(index != -1){
    // extract text after the desired search key
    var value:String = text.substring(index + key.length);
    // parseInt will read until it hits a non-numeric character
    var net_port1:int = parseInt(value);
    trace(net_port1); // 5331
}
```

Comment: Yes I knew it has something to do with the type of return, I'm using windows by the way.

Comment: I figured that my `(ArrayOfLines[0]);` was outside of the function as well. So that was the problem too. I'm about to post my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me. Thanks again to Aaron for his answer on properties. I may use that in the future.

```
//Read settings from TinkerProxy Config File
var TextFileLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var ArrayOfLines:Array;
var Port:int;
var COM:int;
TextFileLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
TextFileLoader.load(new URLRequest("/tinkerproxy-2_0/serproxy.cfg"));

function findSubstring(array:Array, string:String):int {
    for(var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].indexOf(string) > -1){
            return i;  //Index of Substring
        }
    }
    return -1; //Not Found
}

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
    ArrayOfLines = e.target.data.split(String.fromCharCode(13));

    if(findSubstring(ArrayOfLines, "net_port") > -1){
        Port = Number(ArrayOfLines[findSubstring(ArrayOfLines, "net_port")].split("=")[1]);
    }
    else{
        Port = 5331; //Default if not port is found.
    }

    if(findSubstring(ArrayOfLines, "serial_device1") > -1){
        COM  = Number(ArrayOfLines[findSubstring(ArrayOfLines, "serial_device1")].split("serial_device1=COM")[1]);
    }
    else{
        COM  = 1;   //Default if not port is found.
    }

    trace("COM: " + COM + " Port: " + Port);
}
```